# merge 4 videos and put audio in different tracks/channels

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm pretty new to ffmpeg, so I'm having a bit of a struggle.

I have found a way to merge 4 videos into one side-by-side video grid (2x2) with following code:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0]pad=iw*2:ih*2[a];[1:0]null[b];[2:0]null[c];[3:0]null[d];[a][b]overlay=w[x];[x][c]overlay=0:h[y];[y][d]overlay=w:h" multiple_input_grid.mp4
```

What I would like to do is distribute the audio of each video as follows

- Audio from vid1 to audiotrack 1 -> left channel
- Audio from vid2 to audiotrack 1 -> right channel
- Audio from vid3 to audiotrack 2 -> left channel
- Audio from vid4 to audiotrack 2 -> right channel

So multiple_input_grid.mp4 will have 2 audio tracks with different left/right audio

Is there a way of doing this in ffmpeg?

Thanks

The command I'm using (this should have 4 different sources, but has 4x the same):

```
C:\Users\Gijs\Documents\ffmpeg-20130820-git-68b63a3-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -y -
i VIDEO0050.mp4 -i VIDEO0050.mp4 -i VIDEO0050.mp4 -i VIDEO0050.mp4 -filter_compl
ex "[0:0]pad=iw*2:ih*2[a];[1:0]null[b];[2:0]null[c];[3:0]null[d];[a][b]overlay=w
[x];[x][c]overlay=0:h[y];[y][d]overlay=w:h" multiple_input_grid.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version N-55644-g68b63a3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 19 2013 20:32:00 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 42.100 / 52. 42.100
  libavcodec     55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavformat    55. 13.103 / 55. 13.103
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
  libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VIDEO0050.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
  Duration: 00:00:28.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5298 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 720x1280, 5001 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16, 29.40 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k
tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 95 k
b/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VIDEO0050.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
  Duration: 00:00:28.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5298 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 720x1280, 5001 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16, 29.40 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k
tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 95 k
b/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VIDEO0050.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
  Duration: 00:00:28.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5298 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 720x1280, 5001 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16, 29.40 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k
tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 95 k
b/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VIDEO0050.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
  Duration: 00:00:28.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5298 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 720x1280, 5001 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16, 29.40 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k
tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 95 k
b/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] 264 - core 135 r2345 f0c1c53 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'multiple_input_grid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    encoder         : Lavf55.13.103
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1440x2
560 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 11584 tbn, 30.17 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100
Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-13 13:32:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> pad (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> null (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> null (graph 0)
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> null (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   19 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.94 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s
frame=   42 fps= 41 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s
frame=   46 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s
frame=   54 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=     179kB time=00:00:01.99 bitrate= 735.9kbits/
frame=   58 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=     338kB time=00:00:02.22 bitrate=1245.2kbits/
frame=   65 fps= 17 q=29.0 size=     546kB time=00:00:02.34 bitrate=1908.9kbits/
frame=   73 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     778kB time=00:00:02.57 bitrate=2476.6kbits/
frame=   80 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     927kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate=2599.0kbits/
frame=   85 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    1089kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate=3053.5kbits/
frame=   91 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    1268kB time=00:00:03.15 bitrate=3293.1kbits/
frame=   99 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    1481kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=3462.3kbits/
frame=  107 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    1666kB time=00:00:03.73 bitrate=3653.1kbits/
frame=  115 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    1898kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate=3919.8kbits/
frame=  123 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2121kB time=00:00:04.19 bitrate=4137.0kbits/
frame=  130 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2267kB time=00:00:04.43 bitrate=4190.3kbits/
frame=  135 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2428kB time=00:00:04.66 bitrate=4265.3kbits/
frame=  143 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2625kB time=00:00:04.89 bitrate=4392.4kbits/
frame=  149 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2783kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=4548.5kbits/
frame=  155 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    2984kB time=00:00:05.36 bitrate=4560.0kbits/
frame=  163 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3195kB time=00:00:05.59 bitrate=4680.1kbits/
frame=  171 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3396kB time=00:00:05.82 bitrate=4776.1kbits/
frame=  179 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3573kB time=00:00:06.05 bitrate=4832.0kbits/
frame=  186 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3785kB time=00:00:06.28 bitrate=4929.5kbits/
frame=  192 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3949kB time=00:00:06.52 bitrate=4960.0kbits/
frame=  200 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    4150kB time=00:00:06.75 bitrate=5033.0kbits/
frame=  206 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    4306kB time=00:00:06.87 bitrate=5134.7kbits/
frame=  212 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4513kB time=00:00:07.21 bitrate=5121.3kbits/
frame=  220 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4707kB time=00:00:07.45 bitrate=5175.1kbits/
frame=  228 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4918kB time=00:00:07.68 bitrate=5244.0kbits/
frame=  235 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5068kB time=00:00:07.91 bitrate=5245.4kbits/
frame=  241 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5249kB time=00:00:08.14 bitrate=5277.5kbits/
frame=  248 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5444kB time=00:00:08.37 bitrate=5321.9kbits/
frame=  256 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5666kB time=00:00:08.61 bitrate=5390.4kbits/
frame=  264 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5869kB time=00:00:08.84 bitrate=5436.2kbits/
frame=  268 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    5976kB time=00:00:09.07 bitrate=5393.6kbits/
frame=  276 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    6201kB time=00:00:09.30 bitrate=5457.8kbits/
frame=  284 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    6416kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate=5509.1kbits/
frame=  292 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    6622kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate=5551.1kbits/
frame=  297 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    6744kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=5521.7kbits/
frame=  306 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    7125kB time=00:00:10.23 bitrate=5701.5kbits/
frame=  314 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    7364kB time=00:00:10.46 bitrate=5762.2kbits/
frame=  321 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    7540kB time=00:00:10.70 bitrate=5771.5kbits/
frame=  327 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    7732kB time=00:00:11.04 bitrate=5732.3kbits/
frame=  331 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    7834kB time=00:00:11.16 bitrate=5747.2kbits/
frame=  337 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    8025kB time=00:00:11.28 bitrate=5827.0kbits/
frame=  342 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    8191kB time=00:00:11.39 bitrate=5887.2kbits/
frame=  349 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    8395kB time=00:00:11.63 bitrate=5912.9kbits/
frame=  357 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    8648kB time=00:00:11.97 bitrate=5914.6kbits/
frame=  365 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    8908kB time=00:00:12.21 bitrate=5976.1kbits/
frame=  372 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    9100kB time=00:00:12.44 bitrate=5991.4kbits/
frame=  377 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    9281kB time=00:00:12.55 bitrate=6054.1kbits/
frame=  382 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    9435kB time=00:00:12.79 bitrate=6042.7kbits/
frame=  389 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    9633kB time=00:00:13.02 bitrate=6059.2kbits/
frame=  397 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    9864kB time=00:00:13.25 bitrate=6096.3kbits/
frame=  405 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   10104kB time=00:00:13.48 bitrate=6137.0kbits/
frame=  412 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   10289kB time=00:00:13.83 bitrate=6091.8kbits/
frame=  417 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   10465kB time=00:00:13.95 bitrate=6144.6kbits/
frame=  424 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   10691kB time=00:00:14.18 bitrate=6174.5kbits/
frame=  429 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   10895kB time=00:00:14.30 bitrate=6241.0kbits/
frame=  434 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   11068kB time=00:00:14.41 bitrate=6289.4kbits/
frame=  441 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   11281kB time=00:00:14.76 bitrate=6258.8kbits/
frame=  448 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   11507kB time=00:00:14.99 bitrate=6285.4kbits/
frame=  453 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   11713kB time=00:00:15.11 bitrate=6348.8kbits/
frame=  460 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   11936kB time=00:00:15.34 bitrate=6372.2kbits/
frame=  464 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   12124kB time=00:00:15.57 bitrate=6375.6kbits/
frame=  471 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   12394kB time=00:00:15.80 bitrate=6422.1kbits/
frame=  474 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   12519kB time=00:00:15.80 bitrate=6486.8kbits/
frame=  481 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   12790kB time=00:00:16.04 bitrate=6531.2kbits/
frame=  488 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=   13020kB time=00:00:16.27 bitrate=6553.7kbits/
frame=  493 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   13261kB time=00:00:16.50 bitrate=6581.2kbits/
frame=  499 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   13430kB time=00:00:16.73 bitrate=6572.9kbits/
frame=  504 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   13643kB time=00:00:16.85 bitrate=6631.1kbits/
frame=  508 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   13788kB time=00:00:16.97 bitrate=6655.8kbits/
frame=  514 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   13995kB time=00:00:17.08 bitrate=6709.5kbits/
frame=  519 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   14187kB time=00:00:17.43 bitrate=6665.6kbits/
frame=  525 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   14402kB time=00:00:17.55 bitrate=6722.0kbits/
frame=  531 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   14653kB time=00:00:17.78 bitrate=6750.1kbits/
frame=  537 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   14909kB time=00:00:17.89 bitrate=6823.4kbits/
frame=  544 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   15172kB time=00:00:18.13 bitrate=6854.6kbits/
frame=  553 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   15667kB time=00:00:18.48 bitrate=6945.0kbits/
frame=  558 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   15829kB time=00:00:18.59 bitrate=6972.8kbits/
frame=  564 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   16067kB time=00:00:18.82 bitrate=6990.6kbits/
frame=  570 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   16264kB time=00:00:18.94 bitrate=7033.1kbits/
frame=  576 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   16530kB time=00:00:19.29 bitrate=7019.1kbits/
frame=  582 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   16754kB time=00:00:19.40 bitrate=7071.5kbits/
frame=  588 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   17015kB time=00:00:19.64 bitrate=7096.9kbits/
frame=  595 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   17255kB time=00:00:19.87 bitrate=7112.8kbits/
frame=  601 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   17491kB time=00:00:19.98 bitrate=7168.3kbits/
frame=  606 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   17659kB time=00:00:20.22 bitrate=7153.8kbits/
frame=  611 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   17835kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate=7143.0kbits/
frame=  618 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   18125kB time=00:00:20.56 bitrate=7218.1kbits/
frame=  624 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   18306kB time=00:00:20.80 bitrate=7208.9kbits/
frame=  631 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   18510kB time=00:00:21.15 bitrate=7169.4kbits/
frame=  638 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   18771kB time=00:00:21.26 bitrate=7230.6kbits/
frame=  644 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   18953kB time=00:00:21.49 bitrate=7221.9kbits/
frame=  647 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   19065kB time=00:00:21.61 bitrate=7225.8kbits/
frame=  653 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   19312kB time=00:00:21.73 bitrate=7280.0kbits/
frame=  660 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   19499kB time=00:00:22.07 bitrate=7234.8kbits/
frame=  666 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   19717kB time=00:00:22.19 bitrate=7277.2kbits/
frame=  673 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   19897kB time=00:00:22.42 bitrate=7267.7kbits/
frame=  679 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   20081kB time=00:00:22.54 bitrate=7297.2kbits/
frame=  685 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   20324kB time=00:00:22.89 bitrate=7273.1kbits/
frame=  692 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   20536kB time=00:00:23.12 bitrate=7275.0kbits/
frame=  700 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   20776kB time=00:00:23.47 bitrate=7251.0kbits/
frame=  707 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   20948kB time=00:00:23.58 bitrate=7275.1kbits/
frame=  711 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   21160kB time=00:00:23.70 bitrate=7312.5kbits/
frame=  716 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   21299kB time=00:00:23.82 bitrate=7324.8kbits/
frame=  722 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   21472kB time=00:00:24.16 bitrate=7277.8kbits/
frame=  728 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   21674kB time=00:00:24.28 bitrate=7311.2kbits/
frame=  736 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   21912kB time=00:00:24.63 bitrate=7287.1kbits/
frame=  744 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   22163kB time=00:00:24.86 bitrate=7301.6kbits/
frame=  749 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   22354kB time=00:00:24.98 bitrate=7330.2kbits/
frame=  755 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   22555kB time=00:00:25.09 bitrate=7362.0kbits/
frame=  761 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   22739kB time=00:00:25.33 bitrate=7354.2kbits/
frame=  767 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   23006kB time=00:00:25.56 bitrate=7372.7kbits/
frame=  774 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   23232kB time=00:00:25.79 bitrate=7378.2kbits/
frame=  781 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   23464kB time=00:00:26.02 bitrate=7385.5kbits/
frame=  788 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   23711kB time=00:00:26.14 bitrate=7430.0kbits/
frame=  792 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   23853kB time=00:00:26.25 bitrate=7441.6kbits/
frame=  799 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   24083kB time=00:00:26.60 bitrate=7414.9kbits/
frame=  806 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   24519kB time=00:00:26.83 bitrate=7483.7kbits/
frame=  813 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   24713kB time=00:00:27.07 bitrate=7478.3kbits/
frame=  818 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   24926kB time=00:00:27.18 bitrate=7510.7kbits/
frame=  823 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   25074kB time=00:00:27.41 bitrate=7491.2kbits/
frame=  830 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   25314kB time=00:00:27.65 bitrate=7499.2kbits/
frame=  836 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   25541kB time=00:00:27.76 bitrate=7535.0kbits/
frame=  841 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   25669kB time=00:00:28.00 bitrate=7510.0kbits/
frame=  850 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=   25971kB time=-577014:-32:-22.-77 bitrate=N/A
frame=  850 fps= 10 q=-1.0 Lsize=   27415kB time=00:00:28.37 bitrate=7915.7kbits
/s dup=21 drop=0
video:26940kB audio:444kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.113344
%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] frame I:4     Avg QP:20.92  size:166382
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] frame P:246   Avg QP:23.11  size: 60370
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] frame B:600   Avg QP:26.45  size: 20116
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] consecutive B-frames:  4.2%  1.9%  9.2% 84.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] mb I  I16..4: 12.5% 73.1% 14.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  3.4%  0.5%  P16..4: 55.6% 14.5
%  7.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:16.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 43.8%  3.9
%  0.8%  direct: 2.9%  skip:48.0%  L0:50.7% L1:46.7% BI: 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] 8x8 transform intra:60.5% inter:79.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.1% 56.3% 11.6% inter: 1
4.5% 16.6% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 23% 12% 31%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 15% 25%  6%  4%
 5%  4%  9%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 14% 13%  6%  6%
 7%  4%  8%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 14% 21%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.8% UV:2.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] ref P L0: 58.0%  6.9% 26.5%  8.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] ref B L0: 86.3% 10.7%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] ref B L1: 93.4%  6.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002788fc0] kb/s:7832.26
```

Comment: It is possible, but you need to include the complete ffmpeg console output from your command so I can give you an example.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I've added the output to my post.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard could you give me an example?

Comment: Why are you using the `null` filter?

Comment: Because I'm a noob basically :) I took the code from an example which had some filters and replaced them with null because I didn't want them.

Comment: Ah. I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: scaled grid example]
*Example of 2x2 overlay grid (vertical orientation as in Gijserman's inputs)*

#### Create 2x2 grid overlay and combine 4 mono inputs into 1 stereo output

Example using the [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) video filter to create the background, [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) video filter to place each video, [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) audio filter to merge all audio streams into one 4 channel stream, and [`pan`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) audio filter to combine the resulting 4 channels into stereo (`vid1.mp4` and `vid3.mp4` audio into left channel, `vid2.mp4` and `vid4.mp4` audio into right channel):

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih*2[bg]; \
 [bg][1:v]overlay=w[z]; \
 [z][2:v]overlay=0:h[y]; \
 [y][3:v]overlay=w:h; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" \
output.mp4
```

or you can simply use `-ac 2` instead of `pan`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih*2[bg]; \
 [bg][1:v]overlay=w[z]; \
 [z][2:v]overlay=0:h[y]; \
 [y][3:v]overlay=w:h; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4" \
-ac 2 output.mp4
```

The advantage of `pan` over `-ac 2`, I believe, is that `pan` can renormalize gain to avoid clipping noise. This is why the first example is quieter.

Note that if your inputs contain more than one audio stream then your stream specifiers must be more specific, such as `[2:a:0]` (first [`0`] audio stream [`a`] of the third input [`2`]).

#### Create 2x2 grid overlay and combine 4 mono inputs into 2 stereo outputs

Same as above, but `vid1.mp4` (left channel) and `vid2.mp4` (right channel) audio will be one stereo output stream, and `vid3.mp4` (left channel) and `vid4.mp4` (right channel) audio will be the second output audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih*2[bg]; \
 [bg][1:v]overlay=w[z]; \
 [z][2:v]overlay=0:h[y]; \
 [y][3:v]overlay=w:h; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge;
 [2:a][3:a]amerge" \
output.mp4
```

#### Create 2x2 grid overlay and combine 4 stereo inputs into 2 stereo outputs

- The stereo audio from `vid1.mp4` will become the left channel of the
  first output stereo stream.
- The stereo audio from `vid2.mp4` will become the right channel of the
  first output stereo stream.
- The stereo audio from `vid3.mp4` will become the left channel of the
  second output stereo stream.
- The stereo audio from `vid4.mp4` will become the right channel of the
  second output stereo stream.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih*2[bg]; \
 [bg][1:v]overlay=w[z]; \
 [z][2:v]overlay=0:h[y]; \
 [y][3:v]overlay=w:h[vid]; \
 [0:a]pan=stereo:c0<c0+c1[left1]; \
 [1:a]pan=stereo:c1<c0+c1[right1]; \
 [left1][right1]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[audio1]; \
 [2:a]pan=stereo:c0<c0+c1[left2]; \
 [3:a]pan=stereo:c1<c0+c1[right2]; \
 [left2][right2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[audio2]" \
-map "[vid]" -map "[audio1]" -map "[audio2]" output.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's almost what I want to do. The only thing I want differently is that the resulting video should have 2 stereo audio tracks, so a combination of mapping and panning I guess

Comment: @Gijserman I added another example that creates two stereo audio output streams.

Comment: I get an error:  

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

If I add =inputs=2,pan=stereo:c0<c0:c1<c1 to both amerges I don't get an error, but some audio doesn't make it to the output.  

Also tried amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo:c0<c0:c1<c1; [2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo:c0<c2:c1<c3 without success.

Comment: @Gijserman You will need to include your complete ffmpeg command and the full console output. Use pastebin.com or similar and provide a link.

Comment: @Gijserman All of your audio inputs are stereo. How many stereo audio streams should the output file contain?

Comment: 2 stereo streams, or better said: 4 mono streams. Each mono should be the (stereo converted to mono) audio from one video

Comment: The sound from every video should be converted to mono so we have 4 mono tracks V1, V2, V3, V4. The output has 2 stereo tracks: L1, R1, L2, R2. That's where the 4 mono tracks are put in. L1=V1, R1=V2, L2=V3, R2=V4